I can't figure out how to (whether to) report an unethical culture
EDIT: this is different from the other questions on ethics because I’ve already reported it and nothing was done. I’m now faced with the decision of how to elevate it, if it all.
I'm a new employee in a well known company in a regulated industry (think: banking, nuclear energy, etc.)
I discovered that we're publishing fake customer testimonials. They set off all the alarm bells: SEO keyword stuffing, similar grammar and length, all 10/10 ratings, all "submitted" around the same time. (If I noticed this, others will too.) I found out this happened because the CEO asked staff to submit these.
Meanwhile, our company ethics and values are repeated passionately in every all-hands meeting. My boss's boss is very energized about this. He and I have a good relationship, btw.
I shared my discovery w/ my boss in person, 1-on-1, saying this is very sensitive. She reacted positively, saying it's not sensitive, it's ok to talk about. She directed me to our marketing guy, who said he'd remove them, and then didn't.
Now, this week, our team listed our 9/10 overall testimonial rating as an accomplishment to be proud of. They joked about their family & friends contributing.

So I see two problems:

the false testimonials
the eroding of ethics in the culture

For me, this is a real risk: I want to get my bonus. I don't want the company caught up in a public scandal.
What should my next action be?

I could do nothing because I've reported it.
I could go back to my boss and include the cultural aspect. Maybe I'd also say I'd like to ask my boss's boss to talk to the CEO and help reset the culture.
I could go directly to my boss's boss who likes me and wants me to communicate more with him. And he's really into our values. I believe he'd be a good one to help guide the CEO to the right path.


You have a moral and ethical decision to make, report it to the regulatory body or a news organization and look for a new job due to the fallout, or leave your position after finding a new position under protest of the fake reviews

Trying to fix it internally by going over the heads of the perpetrators is possible but risky; it may leave you actively disliked by a significant number of cow-orkers. You may want to consider if it can be done anonymously, and then make sure you phrase the heads-up in a way that won't re-identify you. If you go outside the company, you should  have your next job lined up before pulling that trigger; your job may be toast, and the whole company may be ashes.

Does this answer your question? Should I report an unethical behavior from a teammate to our leader?

VTC - this question: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/188692/should-i-report-an-unethical-behavior-from-a-teammate-to-our-leader/188693#188693 and my answer is IMO applicable here.

I’ve already reported it.  My question is how to handle the degradation in culture that I’ve now observed.

Apologies for the Double post - If you have already reported it - there are two options: You keep going up the chain until you get a response you like (Middle Management, Upper Management, C-Suite, CEO, Board of Directors, Regulatory body etc.) - and you need to be prepared to be fired and face legal action - or - you live with yourself. I recommend the former as the right thing to do - but eitherway it doesn't change much.

Are you convinced higher-up is not aware or even the instigator?

Your company is large enough to have an audit/ethics/compliance department and they should have a way to report what you believe to be ethics violations, possibly even anonymously. I worked for a relatively small company in the past and we had one.

You've spoken to your manager about it. You've spoken to the marketing person about it. I'd say you did your duty and now it's up to someone else to take up the cause. I'd suggest dropping the matter. If you find this issue to be so egregious to you as to be untenable, then you might consider moving on to another job at another company.

"I found out this happened because the CEO asked staff to submit these." The highest boss in the company ordered the employees to do this. So, there is not much you can do here.

I would give you two advises: get the bonus and get out! :-)

Since you are in a highly regulated industry, there is likely a method of reporting to a compliance officer. This might be "Chief Compliance Officer", "Chief Regulatory Officer", or "Chief Legal Officer".
If there is a way to report anonomously, try it first.
Most successful businesses are risk averse. Highly regulated businesses typically are doubly so. It may seem like a small matter, but they likely would nip this behavior in bud quickly if the right people knew about it.

In a highly regulated industry there should also be external regulatory boards which probably have whistleblower functions.

@PeterM  very true. For this item, where hopefully it is a rouge marketing person and a lazy manager, in house can fix it quickly.

@DJClayworth Thanks for catching my mistype.

Let it go. Choose your battles. You should care about ethics, and you should also be able to tell the difference between a small issue and a big issue. This is not a big issue.
You should keep this between you and your manager. If you can't persuade your manager, you'll be about as persuasive as a horse fly to anyone else. If you go above your manager it just means you're someone your manager can't really collaborate with, because you don't know how to keep disagreements within your working relationship.
Lastly, no one owes you an explanation for how they handle this. For all you know, the marketer is about to be fired over this, and obviously no one would be keeping you in the loop about that. You're concerned about this ethics miss but that doesn't make it your responsibility to resolve.

"This is not a big issue." - I think any kind of organised culture of dishonesty towards the public should be regarded as a big issue, not least in any kind of regulated sector. It's also quite right that something is seen to be done about it - such as reprimanding the marketing director, and reversing the dishonest influence exerted upon the public - otherwise the OPs complaint should additionally be about a culture of concealing dishonesty when it is found and acknowledged, and that is even more serious again.

IMHO it becomes a big issue if the "fake reviews" contain factual errors or deliberate attempts to mislead (e.g. "I know the packaging says diabetics shouldn't take this product, but I did and I've never felt better"). If it is purely about attempts to up the score I would see it as smaller.

@Steve Did you stop reading at that line or do you have better advice than persuade their manager and quit fighting if they can't?

@JoeStevens at that point it's a compliance issue and I'd have some assurance that certain individuals in the company would care. I still wouldn't undercut my manager over it.

@djechlin, no I read your answer to the bottom line. That's why I included the part about how there should be something visibly done about it, since you concluded by essentially saying the OP should not expect to hear any more about it. You seem to be promoting a culture of unaccountability which is completely contrary to the proper order of things, certainly in a regulated profession. There should now be a minimum of either an explanation to the OP why the company officially does not agree the reviews are fake and he is mistaken, or there should be a withdrawal of them.

@Steve ok that I stand by, something should not be "visibly" done about it, generally discipline should be handled in private, and no I do not think there should be a culture of accountability to someone just because they lodged a complaint with a different organization.

@Steve also I'm not really promoting anything since I don't work there or have any power there. I'm promoting OP reacting to a culture of unaccountability (should they go that route) without making career-limiting moves. Like I'm really opposed to these answers writing about what they would do if they were CEO and just implying OP should react with indignation if that doesn't happen. That's giving advice to all parties except the person who's actually asking for advice.

@djechlin, the disciplinary process (if any) does not need to be public. What needs to be, is either a public retraction of fake reviews and a declaration to all of the honest approach in future, or perhaps a private explanation to the OP about why the reviews are not fake. Either way, it should be visible to the OP that something has happened. I grant that there is probably no specific legal obligation to respond to the OP or do anything if there is no wrongdoing, but in that case he would only continue to raise the perceived issue higher and higher whilst no action seems to be getting taken.

@djechlin You do you, I guess. But I wouldn’t recommend that anyone else actually allows human lives to be put at risk rather than upsetting their boss. We would be getting into “Nuremberg Trials” territory here - at some point you don’t follow orders.

@JoeStevens just to put this clearly...  my advice is to choose your battles. You think that advice is wrong, you should actually fight every fight as if you're being asked to run a death camp. After all a fake Yelp review could by some strange sequence of events lead to mass casualties.

@djechlin To recap, I was talking about a scenario where fake reviews explicitly contained false health claims (eg that a product was safe for diabetics when it wasn’t). In that scenario it isn’t difficult to see how such reviews could actually cause casualties.

For unethical companies; "Ethics" is what they will fire those they want to fire over, while those in control can (and will) do whatever they want.
This puts you in a bad spot, where you are both obligated to report it, and yet the company might not comply.  With this combination, the best approach is to ensure that you have reported it in documented ways, and keep backups of the documents offline at home, should an investigation ever occur.
Beyond that, I wouldn't push the matter much further, provided you used the company's correct reporting procedures.
I too worked in a highly regulated industry that seemed to take great liberties with some of the regulation points.  Eventually they were caught, and for their violations, they paid some pretty massive fines.  That said, the fines were a drop in the bucket compared to the money they made, and it seemed like they were in the business of (in addition to that industry) violating the regulations for profit.
This kind of behavior is part of the reason why there is a ranking of "best to worst" banks.  The ones at the top would take your complaint seriously and act on it.  The ones nearer the bottom would generally blow it off they way you are seeing.  That said, many of the most successful companies have histories of breaking the law, because they are run by people who trust that the fine is always less than the money obtained.
So, in short, follow the procedures they recommend, and keep a paper trail outside of the company's reach that covers your actions.  Additionally, you might want to hire a lawyer (don't use any company counsel) for a few hours to properly consult you on how to protect your interests should the company decided it's better "fix" your reporting than to "fix" their violation(s).

Where exactly are these fake customer reviews published?
If they only appear on your company website, this is still clearly unethical but probably not a big deal and will have little to no consequences if found out.
If they are published at some external place than whoever maintains that place will have rules about customer reviews. These rules will in all likelyhood say that fake reviews are not acceptable. First report internally that you are breaking these external rules. If you are told this is fine, you can decide whether you want to report this to the external place.
You wrote you are in a highly regulated industry, if these customer reports are something you are legally required to publish, there will also be rules about this and there is some government agency whose reponsibility it is to enforce them. So this works essentially the same as publishing at some external place.
